# Merge rows based on value without using xlswriter but by using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to output a Pandas dataframe into an excel file using pandas dataframe
need to merge rows with same value in column pandas.

eg :

```
pd.DataFrame({' Name': ['ravi', 'ravi', 'manu'],
'Bag': ['123', '123', '129'],
'Serial Number': ['336', '337','335']})
```

Need to merge both the rows (Name and Bag) as they are having same values

I was not able to merge those rows using pandas

Comment: and what to do with serial number on merge?

Answer (score 0):

If need merge same values in Excel convert first columns to `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({' Name': ['ravi', 'ravi', 'manu'],
                    'Bag': ['123', '123', '129'],
                    'Serial Number': ['336', '337','335']})

df = df.set_index([' Name', 'Bag'])
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', merge_cells=True)
```

Comment: <ipython-input-77-ae3f4c2d4729>:1: FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of DataFrame.set_index except for the argument 'keys' will be keyword-only.
This warning is being raised and the rows are stiil not merged

Comment: @LenateJohn - Problem is with your data in question? Or with real data which are different?